# Google Map is Not displaying properly in Chrome , if map is dragged , it shows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I know this has been discussed many time before , but non of the questions answers my problem. 
I am displaying an image in modal dialog with EXIF data to the side and google map below the with the extracted data about the longitude and latitude for that specific image. I have a gallery of images.  IT IS VISIBLE IN MOZILLA. 
Once i open the modal dialog the map is visible with grey background , i can drag it and then i can see the location but once i release the dragging it hides . Image of it can be seen here: https://jefrey12212445.imgur.com/all.

I am also getting an error in the console on page load : 
`InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: not a number` related to my API : js?key=MY_API&libraries=places&callback=initMap:69

It might be related , i am getting my latitude and longitude in floating point  numbers . Could this be the issue  ?

I am opening the html page with Live server from Visual Studio
1.I have tried , making the `height:100%` and `width:100%`  .
2.Clearing browser data /cookies ( gsScrolPos cookies are not appearing) 
3.Opening the page in Incognito tab.
4.Tried setting `mapTypeID : google.maps.MapTypeId = ROADMAP` in my function `initMap()`

```
<div id="imageContainer"></div>
<div>
   <div id="myModal" class="modal" >
           <img id="current" class="modal-content">
           <pre id="exifResult"></pre>
           <div id="map"></div>
       <span class="close" onclick="spanClick()" style="color: 
     white">Close</span>
  </div>
</div>

$img.click(function() {
$('.modal-content').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
modal.css('display', 'block');
EXIF.getData(this, function() {

    const make = EXIF.getAllTags(this);
        let exifData = Object.entries(make).map(([property, value]) => {
            return `${property}: ${value}`;
        })
        result.text(exifData.join('\n'));


        if (this.exifdata.GPSLatitude && this.exifdata.GPSLatitude.length > 0) {
            let latDegree = parseFloat(this.exifdata.GPSLatitude[0].numerator);
            let latMinute = parseFloat(this.exifdata.GPSLatitude[1].numerator);
            let latSecond = parseInt(this.exifdata.GPSLatitude[2]);
            let latDirection = this.exifdata.GPSLatitudeRef;
            latFinal = ConvertDMSToDD(latDegree, latMinute, latSecond, latDirection);
        }

        if (this.exifdata.GPSLongitudeRef && this.exifdata.GPSLongitudeRef.length > 0) {
            let lonDegree = parseFloat(this.exifdata.GPSLongitude[0].numerator);
            let lonMinute = parseFloat(this.exifdata.GPSLongitude[1].numerator);
            let lonSecond = parseInt(this.exifdata.GPSLongitude[2]);
            let lonDirection = this.exifdata.GPSLongitudeRef;
            lonFinal = ConvertDMSToDD(lonDegree, lonMinute, lonSecond, lonDirection);
        }

        if (latFinal && lonFinal) {
            initMap(latFinal, lonFinal);
        } else {
            googleMap.css('display','none');

        }
   })
})



    function initMap(latFinal,lonFinal) {
          mapOptions = {
             center: {lat: latFinal, lng: lonFinal},
             zoom: 12,
             mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
           };
         let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            mapOptions);

    };
```

I want the map to be seen as in Mozilla Firefox , snippet here: https://jefrey12212445.imgur.com/all

Comment: i am also facing the same issue,tried many solutions but nothing worked

Comment: please let me know if you got any solution for this

Comment: i do not work on this project anymore, so i can not be sure if it still happens , sorry :(